# How to start a script based on an event?

Tags: python, bash, redhat

I'm in a red hat environment.
I need to move a file from server A to server B when a file is available in a folder F.

THere's no constraint on the method used. Is it possible to trigger this event in python or any other scripts?

It could be run as a daemon but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any advices?

Comment: Thank you all for the different options. It's hard to pick an answer because there's so many great solutions. Since I need to pick one, I'll pick the first one that came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple to implement in BASH and also in Python:
Here is my 2 Cent BASH example:

```
 triger=0
 while [ $triger -ne 1 ];  do sleep 3;  
       if [ -f NameOfFile ];
       then
       echo "FileFound";
       sh YourScriptToLaunch
       triger=1
       fi
 echo "sleeping ..."
 done
```

Run this in a shell, you'll see the message sleeping every 3 seconds.
Then from another shell session to in the directory where you ran the script do "touch 
NameOfFile" the script will break and try to launch the script YourScriptToLaunch.

Comment: That's a nice method but the process dies after a file is found. I would remove the triger=1 part.

Comment: No problem, you can change this while loop to run infinitely. Since I didn't know your needs, I gave a general example of observing files appearance in BASH's while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a daemon that will watch the file system (Folder F) and then run some script (move the file from A to B). I know of [two](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki) [libraries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/python-fam/) and a [writeup](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html).

Comment: Does anyone use FAM anymore? I though inotify pretty much destroyed it. Also, Tim's writeup is Windows specific whereas this question is tagged `RedHat` and `bash`.

Comment: `pyinotify` is the linux variant of this.

Comment: `pyinotify` are python bindings for inotify. It's not a Linux "variant" really.

Answer (score 1):

If your folder `F` is on machine `A`, then watch for it using inotify and then just copy it over. You don't need python. Here's a shell one liner that does it for you.

```
if [ $(inotifywait -e create . --format %f) = "your_special_file" ]
then
# Run command to copy your special file
fi
```

You can stick that into a while true loop to run forever daemon style.

inotifywait is part of the [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) suite and it available in Debian and probably RedHat as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- In your script, you can have a loop that sleeps for a couple of seconds (or even 5 minutes) and then checks whether the file exists. This is called "busy waiting" but since you let the process sleep between the checks, the computer won't notice.
- You can use a system service like inotify ([Python module](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki)) to put the script to sleep unless the file changes/is created.

The latter approach uses less resources but is much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

The inotify system of Linux is meant to assist with tasks like this. One tool that should work fine for your needs, even if its a bit old, is `fsniper`. You can read about it and download it from here:
http://files.minuslab.net/doc.html

One thing worth mentioning is to properly test this tool, aswell as other ways you might want to try, so that it doesn't copy incomplete files. I've had issues with that in the past, for example when the purpose is to copy files from a temporary FTP server, if proper checks aren't in place it often happened that the file was copied half-way through its upload. Just wanted to mention this since its often overlooked, and its confusing with corrupt files. :P

Answer (score -1):

This is a job for cron. Cron man, man cron!

Comment: No. I need something instant. I can't have the wait in between 2 cron jobs.

Comment: You can set your cron to run every minute. If you have to have it truly instantaneously though it wouldn't work.

Comment: -1. This is not a job for cron (atleast not in 2012). Cron is used for repeated tasks that run at specific times. Not for something that should run based on an event.